# INSERT INTO/SELECT ONLY INSERTS ONE ROW

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I am having a problem with my SQL Insert into/select.

```
INSERT INTO TBLPMHISTORY(RELEQUIPMENTID,DTETHISPMDUE,STRCAMPUS,STRROOM)
(SELECT INTEQUIPMENTID,DTEPMDATENEXTDUE,STRCAMPUS,STRROOM
FROM TBLEQUIPMENT
WHERE DTEPMDATENEXTDUE BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD("DAY",21,GETDATE()))
```

It only seems to insert one row into the new table, but when I run the SELECT part of the statement on its own, it comes back with 84 rows.

I am not sure if there is something that is limiting the bulk insert or not but any help would be much appreciated.

The code to create the PMHISTORY Table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TBLPMHISTORY( 
INTPMHISTORYID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
RELEQUIPMENTID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TBLEQUIPMENT(INTEQUIPMENTID), 
STRDESCRIPTION VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT 'Preventative Maintenance', 
DTETHISPMDUE DATETIME, 
YSNPMDONE BIT DEFAULT '0', 
YSNPMCONVERTEDTOJOB BIT DEFAULT '0', 
INTRELATEDJOBNUMBER INT DEFAULT '0', 
STRCAMPUS VARCHAR(30), 
STRROOM VARCHAR(30)) 

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PMHistory_DTETHISPMDUE] ON TBLPMHISTORY( DTETHISPMDUE) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: You're not getting any errors back?  Do you have any sort of unique constraints or keys that would prevent possible duplicate values on `TBLPMHISTORY`?

Comment: Are there triggers at play?

Comment: There aren't any triggers at play.  I have put the code that I used to create the PMHistory table above.  It does have a unique nonclustered index to prevent duplicates, ahh...which is the problem as they all have the same PMDUEDATE which is what the constraint is on....   Can I put a constraint on two fields using nonclustered indexes?

Comment: As soon as I remove the index it worked fine... I will have to look into it further..  As I want it to scan the database each day and when it sees that an item is due for a PM anytime in the next couple of weeks it imports it into the database so I don't want any duplicates...

Comment: Figured it out.  Just added the intequipmentid and the DTETHISPMDUE fields to the nonclustered index and now it works fine.  First time the insert into runs it imports 84 records in.  If I run it again it ignores them as duplicates..  Thank you very much Adam.  You pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Surely you are getting a unique constraint error! You will continue to get them if you try to insert duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have constraints in your table TBLPMHISTORY such as DTETHISPMDUE can't be null and the select may contain null values for that column. It doesn't have to be exactly that column, it can be any other columns in the destination table. You should check for the invalid records in the source table.

Answer (score 1):

Your index is using `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON`.

This means inserted rows that violate the uniqueness of this index will be ignored, i.e. not inserted.

Usually, you would have this option set to `OFF`.

Comment: Erm, that's not right. The second row you try to insert is ignored, i.e. discarded, as I said in my post. Try it with a simple test if you don't believe me. You do get a warning, but the duplicate row is discarded. What you describe would be more like a merge.

Comment: Because this is run every day I want it to discard any duplicates with bringing up an error thus the ignore = ON.